# one column value cannot be greater than another column value in Jtable of java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have 4 columns JTable using Default table model, i am populating two column's from DB, and user have to fill the purchase price and sale price in jTable , i wanna make sale Price cannot be greater than Mrp Please Help me..

Comment: Add a listener to the table and use that to check the entered values at the appropriate moment.

Comment: Extend `DefaultTableModel` and override `setValueAt()` to validate the user input.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13628183/230513).

Comment: Use a custom editor on the Sales Price column. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913767/jtable-alert-on-invalid-value/6914552#6914552.

Answer (score 1):

In what problem? Can you show any relative code? Any way I recomend you write your custom table model extends DefaultTableModel (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), it's more flexible.

Comment: My answer should be comment, but I cant post comments.

Comment: You could make this a better answer by adding a link to the related `JTable` tutorial section.